# Custom apache url-writing, with directory separator

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

Is there any easy/faster way to change url like

```
http://example.com/profile.php?id=52
```

to

```
http://example.com/profile/52/username
```

If I have `$row['id']` and `$row['username']` from database?

I tried,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But, it seems that `number/username` part is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule to this to assign only the number to $1:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work. I just did `http://site.com/profile/52/username` and nothing is showing up

Comment: You (and me) missed a / after the ^. But maybe there are other errors. Maybe it would be useful to enable the logging in mod_rewrite.